# Alignment issue with safari - few px gap

Tags: css, alignment

For some reason my header is not perfectly aligned. I set a width of 100% but there's a few pixels gap (top and left - see picture). How can I fix this? Tks

[image]

```
#header {
position:absolute; 
top:0px; 
left:0px; 
width: 100%;
height:50px;
background: #FFF; /* Fallback background color for non supported browsers */         
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f3F3F3); /* Firefox 3.6 */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #F3F3F3),color-stop(1, #fff)); /* Safari & Chrome */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#F3F3F3'); /* IE6 & IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#F3F3F3')"; /* IE8 */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
html, body
{
margin:0;   
padding:0;   
}
```

There's a default margin or padding to html or body tags. This should clear it off.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css.

```
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening, is most likely because your `#header` is positioned absolutely *relative* to the `body` which probably has a padding or margin. *or* it may be positioned relatively to the `html` which may have a padding or margin.

So either try setting padding and margin for `html` to `0`, or for the `body`

```
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

OR

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

OR both :)

Definitely *don't* do what Marko Franceković suggested as that sets the padding and margin of ALL your elements to `0`